# Bootstrap space between columns

Tags: html, validation, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have this form with some inputs:
[image: My inputs]

I would like to make the space between the input and the + and = symbols to be smaller. This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-lg-10 grupo">

                    <div class="col-lg-2 grupo">
                         <input id="num1" class="sum form-control input-sm" type="text"          name="num1" value=" {$unique_id}" readonly="readonly" /> </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-1 grupo">
                         <label class="" >+</label> </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-2 grupo">
                         <input id="num2" class="sum form-control input-sm" type="text" name="num2" value=" {$unique_id2}" readonly="readonly" /></div>
                     <div class="col-lg-1 grupo">
                         <label class="" >=</label> </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4 grupo">
                         <input id="captcha" class="captcha form-control input-sm" type="text" name="captcha" style="width:20%" maxlength="2" />
                    </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

If i leave the input and label in the same col

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to do this. Here is a simple, easy way to get it done as well as maintain responsive qualities:

http://jsfiddle.net/hHWeG/

```
.form-group span {
    margin-left: 0.75em;
}

<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="num1" class="sum col-xs-10 input-sm" type="text" name="num1" value=" {$unique_id}" readonly="readonly" /> <span>+</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="num2" class="sum col-xs-10 input-sm" type="text" name="num2" value=" {$unique_id2}" readonly="readonly" /> <span>=</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <input id="input" class="col-xs-10 input-sm" type="text" name="" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The labels are inside divs with the col-lg-1 class so they'll always be a full column's width. Consider moving them into the same container as the inputs and styling from there.

Comment: When i do this it shows the symbol below the input, see the image in the question at the end @desbo